# Calculando Ano Bissexto de Ano Inicio a Ano Final

Tags: python-3.x

Ola, tem um exercicio onde o mesmo informar o seguinte:

"
Você sabe o que são anos bissextos? Resumidamente, em anos bissextos o mês de fevereiro é mais extenso, passando de 28 para 29 dias. O cálculo para descobrir se um ano é bissexto também é bastante simples, pois um ano é bissexto se é divisível por 4 e não por 100, ou se é divisível por 400.

Claudia adora anos bissextos, porque ela nasceu em um! Mais precisamente, Claudia nasceu no dia 29 de fevereiro, por isso sente que seu aniversário só ocorre "de verdade" nos anos que são bissextos, afinal pode projetar a festa sem ter que explicar aos amigos se comemorará no dia 28 de fevereiro ou no dia 01 de março.

Você foi convidado para a comemoração de Claudia, mas para isso ela pediu um presente especial, solicitou que você construa um programa que a ajude a ficar menos ansiosa para saber quais são os anos em que ela poderá realizar festas na data correta. Para isso, seu programa deverá receber um ano INÍCIO e um ano FIM e exibir todos os anos bissextos do intervalo fechado [ INÍCIO..FIM ]. Ao final, o programa também deve exibir a quantidade de anos bissextos do intervalo.

ENTRADA

Dois números naturais, um em cada linha, que representam o ano INÍCIO e o ano FIM do intervalo considerado. Adote que (0 <= INÍCIO <= FIM <= 9999) sempre será verdade.

SAÍDA

Todos os anos bissextos do intervalo fechado [ INÍCIO..FIM ], um por linha. Ao final, o programa deve exibir a quantidade de anos bissextos, conforme os exemplos.
"

[image: EXEMPLOS ANO BISSEXTO]

O codigo que consegui ate agora, não esta fazendo a contagem dos anos e informando no final a quantidade que é bissexto, segue codigo:

```
ano_inicio = int(input('Digite o ano: '))
ano_fim = int(input('Digite o ano final: '))
calculo = (ano_inicio % 4 == 0 and ano_inicio % 100 != 0) or (ano_inicio % 400 == 0)
contagem = 0

for x in range(ano_inicio, ano_fim+1):
    if calculo:
        pass
    else:
        contagem +=1
        print(f'{x}')
print(f'bissextos: {contagem}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código estava no caminho certo, para contar a quantidade de anos bissextos o que você tinha que verificar é se o ano módulo 4 era igual a zero.

Código corrigido:

```py
ano_inicio = int(input("Digite o ano: "))
ano_fim = int(input("Digite o ano final: "))

contagem = 0

for ano in range(ano_inicio, ano_fim + 1):
    if ano % 4 == 0:
        print(ano)
        contagem += 1
      
print(f"Bissextos: {contagem}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Para responder de forma precisa o seu exercício é só fazer uma correção no código que o amigo postou, além da verificação do sugerida deve se verificar se o resto de 100 é diferente de zero, ou se o resto de 400 também é igual a 0.

```
ano_inicio = int(input())
ano_fim = int(input())

cont = 0

for ano in range(ano_inicio, ano_fim + 1):
    if ano % 4 == 0 and ano % 100 != 0 or ano % 400 == 0:
        print(ano)
        cont += 1
      
print(f'bissextos: {cont}')
```